# Best way to store data (Phones) from Customer before send via AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I developed a Register view and Action on Controller that stores Employee. It's working. But now, I want to send, in one request, my N phones and Employee data. I am doing it using AJAX.

When I add a new phone, I store my list of phones in a variable and send everything by Ajax Post (my Employee ViewModel has many Phones).

But...before sending by ajax, how should I store my phones? In a javascript variable? Local storage? Session with PartialView? only store on the table? How do you guys suggests?

I will have to to this in my update view as well. Should I use PartialView?

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dockerizandu, if my reply is helpful to you, you can accept it as answer, thanks:).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in formData, then use ajax send it to the controller action.

Below is a simple demo.

Model:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public List<int> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Employee
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Add New Employee</h1>

<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Salary</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Salary">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input type="text" name="Phones" class="form-control" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="#" onclick="addPhone(this)">Add more Phone Numbers</a>
    </div>
    <button id="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>


@section scripts{ 
<script>
    function addPhone(e) {
        var x = $('body').find("input[name='Phones']").last().parent();
        var htmlstring = "<div class='form-group'><label>Phone Number</label><input type='text' name='Phones' class='form-control'></div>"
        $(x).append(htmlstring);
    }

    $("#submit").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData();

        var name = $("#Name").val();
        var salary = $("#Salary").val();
    
        formData.append("Name", name);
        formData.append("Salary", salary);
        $("input[name='Phones']").each(function (i) {
            var phones = $(this).val();
            formData.append("Phones", phones);
        });

        $.ajax({
            method:"post",
            url:"/Employee/Create",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {

            }
        })
    })
</script>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create(Employee employee)
{
    return View();
}
```

Result:

[image]